# Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't see partitions

Tags: partitioning

I have some problem. When I bought my laptop (few months ago) - Suse Linux Enterprise Desktop was installed on it. Then I've done the dualboot with Windows 7. And now I want to setup Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop. But during the installation, when I must to choose the partitions etc - installer doesn't see my partitions. I mean, that when ubuntu asks how to configure partitions I choose manually configuring. If I try to boot LiveCD (with this DVD) - Ubuntu can see partitions on fisk -l. But installer can't see them...

What's the problem? (Why did it happen?) How can I fix that without installation at least my windows?

Comment: It is possible that Suse used LVM, which Ubuntu LiveCD doesn't support. Try the Ubuntu alternate CD (the text-mode installer, which supports LVM), to check if it sees your missing "partitions".

Comment: So I need to download Ubuntu alternate and use it to install Ubuntu, right?

Comment: Yes, the LiveCD is more oriented for new users who want to try Linux for the first time and perhaps install it in their Windows computers. Only the most basic packages are included (very squeezed) in the LiveCD. The only fancy thing the LiveCD can do is resize NTFS partitions to make space for Ubuntu. The other fancy features you will find in the alternate CD (it doesn't have a LiveCD environment, so it can fit LVM support in the installer, among other things).

Comment: To see if you are using LVM, try one of the commands "lvs" or "lvdisplay" as root in Suse. If it lists one or more logical volumes, then this is probably why Ubuntu LiveCD cannot see them.

Comment: I've tried commands, whiche you adviced, they're lists nothing, so I think that problem is not in LVM. I downloaded ubuntu alternate but unfourtanately the result is same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using fixparts.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your answer? Think of it as a helpful resource to upcoming viewers.

Comment: Well. I dont remember exactly, but I solved problem using fixparts and this tutorial: http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/

Answer (score 0):

Check whether driver for your hard disk model is present in the Ubuntu installer.

But since Live DVD is able to see the partition the driver should be there in it. Are you using the same DVD to install the OS or using some other installer?

Comment: Yes I'm using the same DVD.

Comment: Check your hard disk model & search whether driver for that model is build-in the Ubuntu DVD.